# using regular expressions in ruby to find a string in quotations

Tags: ruby, regex

I am trying to construct a regex to find a string in ruby

```
str = "foo"
```

I want to be able to stop trying to find the string after it finds the closing quotation mark. I also want to keep the quotation marks so I can output the string I found as:

```
puts "the string is:" + str
=> the string is: "foo"
```

I am pretty new to using regular expressions.

Comment: Can you be more precise about the format of the strings you are trying to match? Will it always be double quotes? Could there be escaped quotes inside the string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a start:

```
/".*?"/
```

Explanation:

```
"    Match a literal double quote.
.*?  Match any characters, as few as possible (non-greedy)
"    Match a second literal double quote.
```

[Rubular](http://rubular.com/r/nr6e67g1wg)

Note that this won't work if the string contains escaped quotes or is quoted with single quotes.

Comment: Rubular is awesome. Just got turned onto it and it saves a lot of time, especially if your new to regular expressions.